# Win11 Explorer: How to CONTROL the columns shown for file listing?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

When I open a folder full of mp3 files, Explorer defaults to a set of media-centric columns that are hostile to my needs.

I want to see file name, creation date, file size... *always*

(And I don't need the metadata about album, etc... ever)

How do I kick Win11 to do the right thing (for me) ?

Comment: If you detest Win11, why not revert to (or install *ab initio*) Windows 10? Win 10 support will last for some years.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I do detest Win11. But the uninstall option is no longer available (curse them). If I have to rip and replace, I will go to OSX (after 30 years on Windows). It is a _lot_ of work to set up a system.

Comment: Or look at Ubuntu. Initial install takes less than 30 minutes, it includes apps such as Firefox browser, Thunderbird email client and LibreOffice Suite (yes, *all* in that initial setup), and can run many windows applications such as 7-Zip in wine. Yes, bringing over data is a bear. though. *sigh*

Comment: Windows has always shown these values for music folders. Since at least Vista, and possibly as far back as XP.